# Terraform AWS, instance not created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm going through the Terraform [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-build?in=terraform/aws-get-started#write-configuration) for AWS. When I apply the Terraform file (exactly as it is in the tutorial), I get:

```
# aws_instance.example will be created
+ resource "aws_instance" "example" {
    ...
  }
  ...
  apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

But when I go to the dashboard of EC2, I don't see the instance. I only have 1 security group.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Here is my region that I set in `aws configure`: `use2-az1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run [terraform show](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/show.html) command in the directory where you ran `terraform apply` it will show you the all the resource created.

Plus don't use AZ ID [AZ IDs for your AWS resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/working-with-az-ids.html)
 even in your configuration for credentials, unless you have a very specific reason to do so.

As per the tutorial you have configured your aws provider:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}
```

Because you mentioned you followed exactly as it is in tutorial , you should be able to see the instance in the respective region which is `us-west-2`.

Comment: Why in my region `us-east-2` there are no AMIs?

Comment: [Working with the AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/getting-started.html). you can switch regions. For AMIs you can browse them via the console.